# What is the UserState variable passed to the ssl verify_fun function

Tags: ssl, erlang, cowboy

I have been trying to get certificate pinning working and I noticed the `UserState` variable that is initially passed to the function defined in `verify_fun`. This variable is returned when the certificate is valid, but I can't find any other mention of it in the documentation.

I would like to store some information from the certificate to later authenticate the client. Can I just pass these information in the `UserState` and later on retrieve them in my webserver (cowboy). Or would I be better off simply validating the certificate in the `verify_fun` and access the certificate information from within cowboy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the final value of `UserState` after the path validation. This parameter is only for passing information to the next stage of the path validation loop: the `verify_fun` will be called once for each extension and problem found in the certificate chain. First, it will get the initial `UserState` as an argument, and in each step it can return a new `UserState` to be used in the next step.

So you should use the `verify_fun` for path validation only. You will have to retrieve the client's certificate again at a later stage to collect and store any data from it.